# Зачем абстрактный класс в java

Tags: java

Java изучаю недавно. Застрял на том, что не могу понять роль абстрактного класса в java. В учебнике (не только в одном) нашел пример, описывающий роль абстрактного класса:

```
// Базовая арифметическая операция
abstract class Operation {
public abstract int calculate(int a, int b);
}
// Сложение
class Addition {
public int calculate(int a, int b) {
return a+b;
}
}
// Вычитание
class Subtraction {
public int calculate(int a, int b) {
return a-b;
}
}
class Test {
public static void main(String s[]) {
Operation o1 = new Addition();
Operation o2 = new Subtraction();
o1.calculate(2, 3);
o2.calculate(3, 5);
}
}
```

Но переделав из абстрактного класса обычный, и даже удалив его вообще программа не перестала работать:

```
// Базовая арифметическая операция
class Operation
{
    public int calculate(int a, int b)
    {
        return a*b;
    }
}
// Сложение
class Addition extends Operation
{
    public int calculate(int a, int b)
    {
        return a+b;
    }
}
// Вычитание
class Subtraction extends Operation
{
    public int calculate(int a, int b)
    {
        return a-b;
    }
}
class Test
{
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        Operation/*Addition*/ o1 = new Addition();
        Operation/*Subtraction*/ o2 = new Subtraction();
        Operation/*Subtraction*/ o3 = new Subtraction();
        Operation o4 = new Operation();
        System.out.println(o1.calculate(2, 3));
        System.out.println(o2.calculate(3, 5));
        System.out.println(o3.calculate(10, 20));
        System.out.println(o4.calculate(10, 10));
        System.out.println(o1.getClass()==o2.getClass());
        System.out.println(o3.getClass()==o2.getClass());
    }
}
```

Опишите, пожалуйста, пример, в котором удаление абстрактного класса (или "переделывание" в обычный) невозможно и приведёт к ошибке, или просто растолкуйте в каких ситуациях обычный класс не заменит абстрактный. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Что за учебник, если не секрет? В приличных книгах по Java все-таки даются основы ООП.

Суть вот в чем. Когда вы отмечаете класс как `abstract` , вы тем самым запрещаете создавать его экземпляры. Поскольку в классе `Operation` не определен метод `calculate`, вы не должны иметь возможность создавать его экземпляры:

```
Operation o = new Operation();
```

Если в классе нет абстрактных методов, то "переделывание" его в обычный никак себя не проявит внешне. Просто появится возможность создать экземпляр этого класса.

Конкретно в вашей "переделке" вы определили тело для метода `calculate`, тем самым изменив логику работы всей  вашей иерархии. Если теперь создать еще один дочерний от `Operation` класс и не определять в нем метод `calculate`, то он будет использовать реализацию из родительского класса, то есть вычислять произведение двух аргументов.

> и даже удалив его вообще программа не перестала работать:

Не верю. Если вы удалили класс `Operation` вам пришлось бы править дочерние классы (убирать `extends` и править `main`). Кроме того после этого ваши классы `Addition` и `Subtraction` стали бы независимыми друг от друга.

Вообще, абстрактные классы широко применяются, когда нужно реализовать некоторую общую функциональность для семейства классов.

Comment: учебник - Курс лекций МФТИ по програмированию на java
собственно я так и сделал ("вам пришлось бы править дочерние классы (убирать extends и править main)").
тоесть другими словами абстрактный класс запрещает создавать экземпляры на себя и обобщает функциональность похожих (дочерных) классов?
и еще вопрос исходя из выше написанной программы (моей):
какие преимущества есть у "урезанного" объекта
Operation o3 = new Subtraction();
над "полным"?
Subtraction o3 = new Subtraction();

Comment: Объект не урезанный. Это использование принципа полиморфизма. Мы объявляем объект как относящийся к более широкому классу и присваиваем ему конкретную реализацию в виде дочернего класса. Таким образом обеспечивается взаимозаменяемость дочерних классов: нам неважно что там подсунуто, мы единообразно работаем с объектами.

Вам бы для начала разобраться с основополагающими принципами ООП. Применительно к Java почитайте Эккеля что ли ("Философия Java").

Answer (score 17):

Коллеги, на мой взгляд конечно, не совсем верно расставляют акценты. В первую очередь абстрактный класс - это конечно же не класс который нельзя создать, а класс реализация которого оторвана от его декларации.

*Абстракция* в общем смысле это отрыв от детализации. В нашем случае, это декларирование класса не заботясь о его реализации. Ну а реализация в каждом случае может быть разной - иногда сложной, иногда простой. А абстрактный класс не имеет реализации.

Попробую привести пример из реальной жизни:

1. Допустим мы хотим описать способы сборки и разборки разной мебели, для чего задаемся классом `Мебель`
2. В данном случае `Мебель` типичный абстрактный класс с двумя абстрактными методами: `Собрать` и `Разобрать`. Поскольку способы сборки и разборки мебели зависят от конкретной модели, то не представляется возможным в классе `Мебель` описать их, поэтому мы и декларируем их как абстрактные.
3. Далее задаемся классом `Стол`, который наследует от класса `Мебель`, в котором реализуем методы `Собрать/Разобрать` - ну что-то типа: прикрутить ножки, то се и проч.
4. Далее задаемся классом `Диван`, который наследует от класса `Мебель`, в котором опять же реализуем методы `Собрать/Разобрать` - теперь: прикрутить спинку, потом подлокотники и проч.

Далее начинается самое интересное и важное ради чего собственно весь это цирк с конями и затевался:

- Если бы не было абстрактных классов то мастеру по сборке приносили бы именно `Столы` и `Диваны`. Ну типа - мастер видит что это `Стол` берет инструкцию по его сборке и собирает. Он должен точно знать что это именно стол или диван иначе труба - сборка не состоится.
- При наличии абстрактного класса мастеру приносят не `Стол` или `Диван`, а просто некую `Мебель`. Мастеру в общем то по барабану стол это или диван или вообще шкаф. Мастер достает из мебели прикрепленный лист с инструкцией и собирает его.

Чувствует разницу?

Comment: Вы скорее описали *интерфейсы*. А фраза "абстрактный класс не имеет реализации" - не верна. Во-первых, абстрактный класс может иметь реализацию, которая будет общей для всех его наследников. Во-вторых, в этом и идея абстрактного класса: вынести реализацию общей функциональности некоторых сущностей в абстрактный класс, а уникальную функциональность обозначить в абстрактных методах.

Comment: Господи, еще один непризнанный гуру :)

Comment: Берем пример с более продвинутых гуру :) А если по делу, в данном конкретном случае, несмотря на все ваши заслуги, вы вводите читателей в заблуждение.

Comment: Судя по вашим комментариям - у вас какая то каша в голове: *абстрактный класс может иметь реализацию, которая будет общей для всех его наследников* - уже даже этот опус наводит на грустные мысли... Оно конечно так, но это общее свойство любого класса, причем тут абстрактный класс?
В общем предлагаю не усугублять дискуссию, вы проголосовали, высказали свое мнение, я свое и на этом закончим :)

Comment: Простите, но правды ради давайте доведем спор до конца. Моя, как вы говорите *каша*, как раз понятна: абстрактный класс *может* иметь реализацию, которая станет общей для его наследников и, при этом, *должен* в абстрактных методах обозначить обязательную к реализации наследниками уникальную для них  функциональность. Ваша позиция: "абстрактный класс не имеет реализации" - не очень понятна. Если можно, проясните вашу мысль. И, пожалуйста, без аргументов  *ad hominem* - неприятно :(

Answer (score 7):

Например, пишем систему учёта самолётов в аэропорте. Есть грузовые и пассажирские самолёты и надо, например, чтоб был список самолётов, которые сейчас в аэропорту.
Делаем абстрактный класс "самолёт" (мы же заранее не знаем, какой самолёт прилетит)
и определяем какие-то базовые поля, пригодные для любого самолёта (скорость полёта и длина, например)

```
public abstract class Flight {
     int speed, width;
}
```

Далее создаём два класса, один для пассажирского самолёта и один для грузового, и в каждом дописываем уже спецефические ему параметры

```
public class PassFlight extends Flight {
     int maxPassengers; //макс число пассажиров
}

public class Freighter extends Flight  {
     int maxCargo;   //макс грузоподъёмность
}
```

Далее уже в классе, который со всем этим делом будет работать, создаём лист и пихаем туда те самолёты, которые прилетают

```
public class Runner{
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
       List<Flight> flightList = new ArrayList<Flight>();
       flightList.add(new PassFlight());
       flightList.add(new Freighter());
    }
}
```

Теперь в принципе понятно, что у нас есть список с самолётами, а какие они - уже не совсем важно. Для меня основная фишка абстрактных классов в том, что с помощью них можно задать логику работы, не реализуя её.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не забываем код оформлять.

Comment: спасибо, надо ещё подучиться.

Answer (score 0):

Собственно главное отличие абстрактного класса от обычного заключается только в том, что у абстрактного класса невозможно создать объект и поэтому он предназначен только для переопределения. А ваш первый пример какой-то неправильный, потому что отсутствует связь между классами Addition, Substraction и Operation.
Пример можно посмотреть, например, [здесь](http://www.javatutorialhub.com/java-abstract-class-method.html).

Comment: собственно я не могу понять что мне даёт связь между ними, если по отдельности они тоже работают. методы определённые в абстрактном классе всё равно нужно еще раз переписывать в дочерних, для меня пока что абстрактный класс выглядит как "очень крутая штука без которой в принципе можно обойтись".

Answer (score 0):

Это нечто среднее между интерфейсом и обычным классом. От класса отличается невозможностью создания экземпляров, а от интерфейса возможностью полноценного объявления методов. удобно, когда для некоего набора классов есть общий метод, но остальные надо переопределить.